# Will yytext be a object of String when I use flex to generate C++ scanner?

Tags: flex-lexer

I'm trying to use Flex to generate a C++ scanner. And I wander the data type of yytext when I use it in my code. Is yytext a string object in this situation? Or is it still a pointer of char? I search for the information but still can't get it.

Here's the code I wrote.

```
%option c++

%option noyywrap

> %{
> 
>   #include <iostream>
> 
>   #include <fstream>
> 
>   #include <stack>
> 
>   using namespace std;
> 
>   stack<string> s;
> 
> %}
> 
> var_string [a-z]+
> 
> var_hybrid \\?\[[0-9]\]
> 
> %%
> 
> assign {BEGIN ASSIGN;} {s.push(yytext);}
> 
> {var_string} {s.push(yytext);}
> 
> {var_hybrid} {s.push(yytext);}
> 
> [ \n\t\r\f]+ {s.push(yytext);}
> 
> . {s.push(yytext);}
> 
> %%
```

I use a stack, and push yytext into the stack.

I can output the content of the stack by using `cout << s.top() << endl;`

Is yytext a string object in this situation?

Answer (score 0):

No, it is a `char*`, just as with the default C scanner. (The `array` option is not available for C++ scanners.)

The C++ standard library includes a converting constructor which implicitly constructs a `std::string` from a C-style string, which is what allows your call to `s.push` to work.